# Finding local maximum and minimum

Tags: calculus

$f(x) = x^5-x^4+x^2-x$ on the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$

The teacher told us that we would have to use Newton's method to solve this problem but I am not sure what to do after taking the derivative.

Comment: Take derivative of $f$, set derivative $f' = 0$, find values of $x$ that make $f' = 0$, then use [second derivative test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative_test).

Comment: I think you can't solve the equation without using the formula for roots of a polynomial of 4th degree.

Comment: so how does the formula for roots of a polynomial of 4th degree work.

Comment: Notice that $f(x) = x(x-1)(x^3+1)$. The polynomial has three real solutions ($x =-1, x = 0$ and $x = 1$). Since  $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} f(x) = -\infty$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} f(x) = +\infty$, $x = 0$ is a saddle-point and there exists a local maximum at $-1 < x < 0$ and a local minimum at $ 0 < x < 1$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

You are looking for the maximum and minimum of the function  These points $$f(x) = x^5-x^4+x^2-x$$ These points corresponds to the zero's of the function $$g(x)=f'(x)=5x^4-4x^3+2x-1$$ So, using Newton method from a guess $x_0$, the iterates will be given by $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{g(x_n)}{g'(x_n)}$$ In your case $$g'(x)=f''(x)=20x^3-12x^2+2$$ Now apply the method starting, for example, at $x_0=-\frac 12$ and then at $x_0=\frac 12$ taking into account Alex Silva's comment.

I am sure that you can take from here.